# Can't resolve the reference 'System.UIntPtr System.nuint::op_Explicit(System.nuint)',Xamarin.Agora.AgoraRtcEngineKit

Tags: xamarin, agora.io

Trying to update [Xamarin.Agora.iOS nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Agora.Full.iOS/3.5.1-beta1) updates (3.5.1-beta1) get this build time error:

```
error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.UIntPtr System.nuint::op_Explicit(System.nuint)', referenced from the method 'System.Int32 DT.Xamarin.Agora.AgoraRtcEngineKit::AdjustUserPlaybackSignalVolume(System.nuint,System.Int32)' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx'.
```

[Xamarin.forms version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/5.0.0.2244) is latest: 5.0.0.2244

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of similar issues opened on the GitHub repo here:
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RTC-SDK-for-Xamarin/issues/32

If you ping the maintainers of that repo they may be able to help

Comment: Thanks, but i already asked them and they asked me to search/post question on SO.